# Error while deploying a python code with mern stack backend using render

Tags: hosting, mern, python-module, modulenotfounderror, render.com

I am working on a web app using mern stack. At initial stage i pushed the backend code into gitHub and deployed it in render and it was working fine. Now i need a functionality. There is a button in my frontend. As i press that button a python code should start running. I build its routes in backend and i used 'child-process' for running python code. It was working properly in localhost. But i tried to push the updated code into git and deploy it in python. I also added requirement.txt and using this file i am downloading the necessary packages needed for python using build command. The modules are installed but as soon as i try to run the python code using routes it is showing that 'No module named pymongo'. But when render is building it is showing pymongo installed.

I tried to run a python code with single click in my mern stack application.

Comment: The issue is resolve. Render doesnt support python runtime in nodejs environment. But it does support nodejs runtime in python environment. So the issue was resolved using python environment. Render has nodejs runtime environment default to any runtime environment we choose.